# Выделение текста курсивом в JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, text

Я создал `JTextPane` и кнопку которая будет делать текст «*курсивом*». Осуществил изменения шрифта так:

```
jTextPane1.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, 16));
```

Вот только изменяется весь текст, а не то что пишу после изменения. Как можно сделать чтобы то, что было ранее написано не подлежало редактированию.

И есть ли в Java возможность работать с выделенным текстом? Например, чтобы я выделил текст и когда нажимаю на кнопку, то изменяется только выделенная часть текста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться действием [`StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction.html), которое включает/отключает выделение курсивом для текстового компонента. При выполнении действие будет применено также для выделенного текста.

Действие можно задать кнопке. Например:

```
JButton italicButton = new JButton(new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());
italicButton.setText("Italic");
```

При нажатии на такую кнопку для `JTextPane`, на котором установлен фокус, будет включаться/отключаться выделение курсивом.

Подробнее настройка текстовых компонентов Swing разбирается в уроке «[Text Component Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html)» из *Java Tutorials*.

Comment: @RickPetrev не нужно в обработчике `jButton2` создавать новый `jButton2`. Нужно в коде инициализации кнопки либо передать `new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction()` в конструктор, либо вызвать метод `jButton2.setAction(new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());`